# How do I call http api in https site?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, api

How do I call http api in https site.My site is using HTTPS.
I am using JS files like:
`//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

I want call below api in javascript code:

`http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=' + pos.coords.latitude + '&lng=' + pos.coords.longitude + '&username=demo`

When I use the api with http, firefox and IE is blocking the api.
When I use the api without http like:

`//api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceNameJSON?lat=' + pos.coords.latitude + '&lng=' + pos.coords.longitude + '&username=demo`
then it converted to https.

But the api is http not https.
So how do i call the above api?

Comment: Running code from HTTP defeats your security.  You _need_ to use an HTTPS API.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that would work is: `Create a https proxy on server side and do the request from there.`